# SQL help - Get top 5 users by highest score on any particular day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that gets top 5 accumulated score from the results table.

```
SELECT qm_1_users.userId, 
       qm_1_users.fname, 
       qm_1_users.lname, 
       SUM(qm_1_results.points) as topScore
  FROM qm_1_results
       INNER JOIN qm_1_users 
           ON qm_1_users.userid=qm_1_results.userid
GROUP BY 
       qm_1_users.userId
ORDER BY 
       topScore DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

I now need it to show the top 5 users who have the highest score achieved on any particular day. So if I played the quiz three times and achieved the following scores (Day 1 = 400, Day 2 = 600, Day 3 = 120), then my top score would be 600. This is where my SQL knowledge struggles.

```
quizid    |   userid    |    questionid     |    points
1             1              1                   50
1             1              2                   50
2             1              1                   50
2             1              2                   50
2             1              3                   50
2             1              4                   50
4             1              1                   50
4             1              2                   50
4             1              3                   50
4             1              3                   50
4             1              4                   50
4             1              5                   50
1             2              1                   50
3             2              1                   50
3             2              2                   50
4             2              1                   50
4             2              2                   50
4             2              3                   50
1             3              1                   50
1             3              1                   50
1             3              1                   50
```

Player 1: Day 1 – 100 points, Day 2 – 200 points, Day 4 – 300 points
Player 2: Day 1 – 50 points, Day 3 – 400 points, Day 4 – 150 points
Player 3: Day 1 – 150 points

The top of the leaderboard would show:

Player 2 – 400 points in position 1
Player 1 – 300 points in position 2
Player 3 – 150 points in position 3

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Add `qm_1_users.fname` and `qm_1_users.lname` to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you must add a filter on a day, so when you sum, only the value of that day can be summarized

Comment: Hi slavoo, that just gives me the same results unfortunately. I'm going to add the tables to show the data

Answer (score 0):

You can group by user and day so you'll get the same result classified by day/person, then you can order by user_id and topScore (but not necessary).

```
SELECT qm_1_users.userId, 
       qm_1_results.day, 
       SUM(qm_1_results.points) as topScore
FROM qm_1_results
       INNER JOIN qm_1_users 
           ON qm_1_users.userid=qm_1_results.userid
GROUP BY 
       qm_1_users.userId, qm_1_results.day
ORDER BY 
       user_id, topScore DESC
```

By this way you'll get something like

```
user1 day1 500
user1 day2 412
user1 day3 660
user2 day1 440
user2 day2 613
user2 day3 360
```

If you add a filter per day at `where` section you can select just this day top five with limit and order. Something like `WHERE qm_1_results.day = '2014-11-05'` I suposse

Comment: thanks Olvathar, I've ran the query and it appears to be listing a row for each day the user has played, is there a way just to show each user once with their highest score?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what you mean, would you be able to show an example?

Comment: Forget last comment it wasn't correct (I pressed enter key before I ended) I have also deleted it.

Comment: Cool, any other ideas?

Comment: If you `JOIN (SELECT MAX(points) as max_points, userid FROM qm_1_results) AS max_per_user ON max_per_user.max_points = qm_1_results.topScore AND qm_1_results.userid = max_per_user.userid` you will filter discarding all but higher values for each user

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've got the following:

`SELECT qm_1_users.userId, 
       qm_1_results.quizid, 
       SUM(qm_1_results.points) as topScore
FROM qm_1_results
JOIN (SELECT MAX(points) as max_points, userid FROM qm_1_results) AS max_per_user ON max_per_user.max_points = qm_1_results.topScore AND qm_1_results.userid = max_per_user.userid
INNER JOIN qm_1_users ON qm_1_users.userid=qm_1_results.userid
GROUP BY qm_1_users.userId, qm_1_results.quizid
ORDER BY userid, topScore DESC `

but I'm getting an error [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'qm_1_results.topScore' in 'on clause'.

Comment: LOL It's true, topscore column doesn't exist, find it and substitute it with "points" which is the correct column name

Comment: i tried that but nothing gets returned unfortunately.

Comment: Ahmm, I've seen the problem, topScore is an addition of values not the highest value for the user as I used it... That's a little more difficult, do you need only one query for doing that, it will result a really weird query

Answer (score 0):

I've finally worked it out. Thanks for all the pointers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(userId), quizid, fname, lname, image, userTypeId, iso, MAX(topScore) as topScore FROM (
        SELECT qm_1_users.userId,
               qm_1_users.fname, qm_1_users.lname, qm_1_users.image, qm_1_users.userTypeId,qm_1_results.quizid, SUM(qm_1_results.points) as topScore, wm_countries.iso
               FROM qm_1_results
               INNER JOIN qm_1_users ON qm_1_users.userid=qm_1_results.userid
       LEFT JOIN wm_countries ON wm_countries.countryId=qm_1_users.countryId
            GROUP BY qm_1_users.userId, qm_1_results.quizid
            ORDER BY topScore DESC, userid DESC
        ) AS x GROUP BY userId
    ORDER BY topScore DESC
LIMIT 5;
```